# Android Material 3 click Animation delayed (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, material3

I attache this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTIjMBtfmiU
In every flutter application I use material 3 the click animation is stuck after clicking it for 0,5 seconds. I use the flutter InkWell for that. Did anybody see the same behavior in his application? When I set material 3 to false, the stuck animation disappear.

Comment: can you include error reproducible code-example